# Cannot load audio file to AudioKit

Tags: ios, xcode, audiokit

So I want to load an audio file to AudioKit and I'm always getting this error. Btw, AudioKit is added in a cocoa touch framework. I've tried playing with the baseDir but still the same error. It is also included Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.

```
let file = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "a4w.wav", baseDir: .resources)
let file = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "a4w.wav", baseDir: .custom)

// All baseDir has the same error.
```

error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -3000.)

Comment: I'd love to be able to answer this question since it has AudioKit in the title, but there really isn't enough information provided to really address it.  I'd say either provide a sample project or just remove the question since all answers would only be guesses at this point.